# The Most General Unifier

Tags: logic, unification

I am studing for logic and i need to unify these formulas:

$$ P(\;\; f(x,g(x,y))\;\; ,\;\; h(z,y)\; ) $$
$$ P(\;\; z \;,\; h(f(u,v),f(a,b))\; ) $$

Can someone explain me what i need to do?
I must replace $\;z/f(x,g(x,y))\;$ or i need to follow some other steps?
I have try to solve it but i don't know if i am going in the right path!
Searching my books i didn't find any similar example. That's why i ask here.

Thanks!

edit: i forgot to tell  $a$ and $b$ are constants, $f$ and $g$ are functions and $x,y,z,u,v$ are variables

Comment: You should re-write your question using [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It is currently difficult to read...

Comment: Ok i will try to rewrite it with mathjax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the second coordinates match one can set $z=f(u,v),y=f(a,b).$ With this value of $z$ matched to the other first coordinate $z=f(x,g(x,y))$ a choice suggests itself, namely that $u=x$ and $v=g(x,y).$ Without further context on what you're trying to do, at least these choices make the two formulas "come out the same".

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did't know that $z$ can be equal to two different values!

Comment: In a way if the two terms match, once $z=f(u,v),y=f(a,b)$ have been chosen to make second coordinates match, all I'm saying is that if one further chooses $u=x,v=g(x,y)$ then it goes through. However one cannot *deduce* from $h(f(u,v),f(a,b))=h(z,y)$ that the individual equations $z=f(u,v)$ and $y=f(a,b)$ follow logically. They *would* follow, provided the function $h$ were known to be one-to-one. [I just made the simplest choices to work.]